# What is the ultimate purpose of physics.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm a newbie here and I've noticed that a lot of the questions are at a pretty high level. (I'm just starting a masters program in physics). Does this site have a philanthropic goal of speeding up the research process or is it merely an experiment in social media? Is it a site that aims to impact the way researchers work or is it like a hobby site, where you get what you want out of it?

My experience has been "so far so good" but I'm curious as to how far I can go with this.

Comment: Duh.  World domination.

Comment: In an ideal world: That the posts become valuable resources of knowledge, as opposed to mere [infotainment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66538/16227).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Stack Exchange sites are run by a for-profit company. Their ultimate goal is to make money by providing a service on the internet. The service is host question-&-answer sites.

The level of each site depends to some degree on decisions made by the user base. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (the original model) accepts questions starting from a very low, [but not trivial level](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Physics.SE is pitched just a little higher than that: we discourage basic pedagogical questions (things that look like "homework") in favor of a conceptual approach to the foundations of our discipline. Note that there <s>is</s> also *used to be* [Theoretical Physics](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/) which <s>is</s> *was* targeted at "research level" theoretical and mathematical physics *but was deemed to be diying and merged with this site, look for [research-level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-level) to find that and related content*.

For other sites in the network, see the bottom of the page and [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (the place where *user input* defines and launches new sites, and where you can find all the beta sites).

Comment: interesting i had no idea this was a normal commercial enterprise, i though it was one of those non-profit wikipedia type deals

Comment: How do they plan to monetize the site? I don't see too many ads around.

Comment: Partly through [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), and partly through the few ads that do show up, but beyond that... I'm not sure. This has definitely been brought up on [metaSO], though, so you could check there and see if you can find any information on it.

Comment: Seems like a good idea for people to be able to pay to host a site. I'd love to see theoretical physics stack exchange take off again, but payed for this time without the pressure to succeed in numbers.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo Early on there was an option to do that. That is, in fact how MathOverflow got going, though there has been some kind of detante recently. Not sure what the current status is.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo I'd like to see a restart of a theoretical physics site (maybe better outside SE because of the pressure to have enough views etc) a lot too. Seems they have tried to do it [here](http://discussion.tpqa.org/), but not much seems to be going on at present. Maybe these efforts could be reactivated? I sadly observe that the number of new good theoretical questions has dramatically dropped since about a month ago and certain theoretical, fundamental, and HEP topics people on TP.SE used to be interested in, are actually fading away here on Physics SE. So a new TP site is really needed.

Comment: _The Stack Exchange sites are run by a for-profit company. Their ultimate goal is to make money by providing a service on the internet. The service is host question-&-answer sites._ I got slammed for saying [the same thing, essentially](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/do-we-agree-with-rons-suspension/2737#2737) (currently at -4 votes).

Comment: To make money out of providing the service of hosting QA sites, someone has to be demanding for them to host these sites, right? Like who exactly is paying then to host the physics Q&A website? Sorry, this probably a very misguided question but I'm naturally dumb at understanding business models ‍♂️