# Why was PhysicsStackExhange made?

Tags: discussion, support

I am curious to know "Why was PhysicsStackExhange made?"I mean certain objectives and did PSE fulfil them?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1096/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5173/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7181/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9115/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also relevant: the 'definition' stage of [the Area 51 proposal for this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908?phase=definition).

Comment: If you want to ask about "certain objectives", you need to say which ones you are asking about.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Look up the wikipedia page of PSE .I think this would suffice:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange