# What would be the goal of this site if all possible questions have been asked and answered?

Tags: discussion

From what I heard since I've joined, I've understood that the purpose of Stack Exchange was to make a knowledge repository, but what if one day we document every single possible question which could be asked?

Would the site change policies if such a day came?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7181/50583, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5173/50583, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1096/50583

Comment: Paging Kurt Godel! Question in Physics Meta!

Comment: What does "paging kurt godel" mean?

Comment: The title doesn't match your question. Are you asking what we are striving for? Or are you asking what happens when we reach what we are striving for?

Comment: What happens the day when the site reaches it's purpose

Comment: @Buraian - do you know who Kurt Godel was, and his Incompleteness Theorem?

Comment: I suggest we delete at that point all homework and assignments questions, and start again!

Comment: Afaik the count of the interesting, essentially different questions is $\aleph_0$.